# How can color the first item in a select?

Tags: html, css

I have this sample:

[link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdaJWe)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<select name="card_type" id="card_type" class="select-full">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="visa">Visa</option>
    <option value="mastercard">Mastercard</option>
    <option value="discovery">Discovery</option>
    <option value="maestro">Maestro</option> 
</select>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
select
{
   color: #ccc;
}
option
{
   color: #000;
}
option:first-child
{
   color: red;
}
```

I have a wish to spot and select only the first item in the list.
The first element to be red and the other to be gray for example.

Is there any possibility to do this?
I tried the above code but does not work. Can you please tell me what is wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is colored correctly. If you open the drop-down you'd see the first item in red. If you are trying to set the color of "Select" to red even when it is selected (whereas the others remain grey when selected) then I don't think it is possible with CSS.

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lcv1eqzs/1/

Comment: @Harry, yes select won't red but when user will click on dropdown then in that open drop down, we can see color.. agree with you.

Comment: did any answer worked for u?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made changes in snippet. Please check it.

is this the way you want?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($(this).val() == 0){
      $('select').css("color","red");
    }
    else{
      
      $('select').css("color","#000")
    }
  $('select').change(function(){
    
    if($(this).val() == 0){
      $('select').css("color","red");
    }
    else{
      
      $('select').css("color","#000")
    }
  })
})
```

```css
select
{
   color: #ccc;
}
option
{
   color: #000;
}
option:first-child
{
   color: red;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="card_type" id="card_type" class="select-full">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
             <option value="visa">Visa</option>
             <option value="mastercard">Mastercard</option>
             <option value="discovery">Discovery</option>
             <option value="maestro">Maestro</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: to you it works to me has not changed anything after I added the code remained the same color ...

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood but what difference is this making to OP's code? You don't even have an item matching `value="0"` in the HTML.

Comment: Sorry my mistake @Harry. I take it as a different way

Comment: So if your code is already right , then can u explain what exactly you want? @JohnSmith

Comment: The first item in the list must have the red color...in your example ... they are all the same color

Comment: can you check it now @JohnSmith. If you want different way then please explain me

Comment: As you can see ... the color is the same. The word "select" must be red

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select:first-child{color: red;}
```

Comment: This will not style the first item in a select. It will style the select that is the first child of its parent. There is a difference between those two.

Answer (score 1):

Use nth-of-type(1)

```
option:nth-of-type(1)
{
   color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well assuming something.

I think you want your `<option value="visa">Visa</option>` to color red but note that this is second option so use this css

```
select.select-full option:nth-child(2){
  color:red;
}
```

fiddle link :https://jsfiddle.net/yudi/L439rrsd/